# "A language isn't something you learn so much as something you join."

Tags: quotations

I read such a quote from [Chapter 1: Building Abstractions with Functions](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/sp12/book/functions.html)

> "A language isn't something you learn so much as something you join."
>   ~Arika Okrent

Honestly , I have little idea what the quote are talking about. Surely it' not that you should learn a language by joining in it society.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be about computer languages.

The idea is that just learning the rules of the language doesn't make you a good programmer in that language. You need to join the culture of the language. You should be actively engaging with other programmers in the same language if you want to write effective, idiomatic, easy-to-maintain code.

So a computer language is not just a set of syntax and processing rules, but an expression of a community of programmes.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the statement that

> A language isn't something you learn so much as something you join.

Is intended to convey that the social customs and information taken for granted by native users of a language is so essential that a person who does not know them well cannot properly understand the language. It might even mean that only a native speaker, or what might be called an **adoptive** native speaker, can fully understand a language. I think that is overstated. But certainly a person who learns a language abstractly and academically, with little or no knowledge of the culture in which it is spoke, will have a very different understanding of it than a native speaker. No one now has the kind of understanding of Latin that a Roman Citizen of the days of Augustus had.